# How can I update img using state change in react with select option?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am trying to update selected language image from select options. My problem is when I update my state selecting new flag it doesnt update image but updates image alt value.
[Here is my current siuation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF6I0.png)
Thanks
What I made here:

```
import unitedkingdom from '../assets/flags/uk.png';
import belgium from '../assets/flags/icons8-belgium-48.png';
import croatia from '../assets/flags/icons8-croatia-48.png';
import czechrepublic from '../assets/flags/icons8-czech-republic-48.png';
import bulgaria from '../assets/flags/icons8-bulgaria-48.png';
export const CountryFlags = () => {
    const { selectedLanguage, setSelectedLanguage } = useContext(AppContext);
    const { Option } = Select;

    return <>{selectedLanguage && <img className="currentlySelectedLanguage" src={selectedLanguage} alt={selectedLanguage} />}
        <Select defaultValue='Lang' onChange={(e) => setSelectedLanguage(e)}>
            <Option value="unitedkingdom"><img className="availableLanguages" src={unitedkingdom} alt="unitedkingdom" /></Option>
            <Option value="belgium"><img className="availableLanguages" src={belgium} alt="belgium" /></Option>

        </Select>
    </>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you got before is because you pass the `string` of the selected language to the `src` prop. In that case he can't resolve that string to a valid image path and therefore shows the `alt` tag which accepts a `string` as a value.

The simplest approach for this is just writing a `switch case` function which returns the correct image on state change:

```js
import unitedkingdom from '../assets/flags/uk.png';
import belgium from '../assets/flags/icons8-belgium-48.png';
import croatia from '../assets/flags/icons8-croatia-48.png';
import czechrepublic from '../assets/flags/icons8-czech-republic-48.png';
import bulgaria from '../assets/flags/icons8-bulgaria-48.png';

const mapLanguageToImg = (language) => {
    switch (language) {
        case 'belgium': return belgium;
        case 'croatia': return croatia;
        case 'czechrepublic': return czechrepublic;
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

and then just use this function as your `src` value:

```
{selectedLanguage && (
    <img src={mapLanguageToImg(selectedLanguage)} {...yourOtherProps} />
)}
```